# PHP: Append every element of array to string/query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a string that has a few of URLs separated by a `|` i.e. `http://URL1|http://URL2|...|http://URL#`

I am trying to build a string to be used in a query so the result will be:

```
$query = "OR page_url LIKE '%http://URL1%' OR page_url LIKE '%http://URL2%' OR page_url LIKE '%http://URL3%'"
```

This string will be added into a query I am preparing

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = 'abc' :urlquery");
$result->bindValue(':urlquery', $query);
```

Would this work? Also is this the best way to run the query where I have `OR page_url LIKE '% ... %'` for every URL?

Comment: "Would this work? "  Shouldn't you try it before posting?

Comment: This will not work.  SQL expects a variable value where `:urlquery` is going, and no value is expected there.  You'll need to do this by concatenating the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating string should be like this

```
$array = explode('|',$string);
```

Then you get an array of all urls. Then you can prepare new string

```
$query = "OR page_url LIKE '%";
foreach($array as $element){
    $query .= $element."%' OR page_url LIKE '%";
}
$query = rtrim($query," OR page_url LIKE '%");
```

I think now you have your query created to use it

Comment: Just missing a `$query .= "%'";` to close off the last URL

Comment: I think that im not rtriming this part of string so it should stay on last one

Comment: For some reason it is removing the the `%'` as well. See [for yourself](http://www.tehplayground.com/#naajoCqNr)

Answer (score 0):

$array =  explode('|', $numbers);

now you have all the URLs in this array. So you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this

```
$urls="'%" . str_replace("|", "%'|'%", $url) . "%'";
```

to make the url like this:

```
'%http://URL1%'|'%http://URL2%'|...|http:%'
```

now split them

```
$split = explode('|', $urls);
```

then implode them:

```
 $query = implode('OR page like ', $split);
```

Comment: Not quite.. This will return `URL1 OR page like URL2 OR page like URL3`. I need `'%URL1%'`and I need `OR PAGE LIKE` to come first